# Is a WCF Web Service an API?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest, soap

I am working on a Visual Studio Application that references a WCF web service, and after some reading online I am pretty confused.

I have read that WCF is a framework for building a web service, but it is not an API. Is this true?

I was under the impression that Web Services are APIs; I always thought that APIs were Software as a Service (SaaS). Doesn't that mean that APIs and Web Services are pretty much the same thing? Or do I have the wrong idea?

Could this be a misconception of my understandings of SOAP and REST?

Basically I want to know whether a WCF built web service counts as an API, and why/why not?

Comment: An API is the contract to use a computer system, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface, WCF is a technology to build web services, which expose an API in the form of operations

Comment: Keep in mind that a web service is kind of API but an API isn't necessarily  a web service and everything will be fine :)

Comment: @Aymeric That's what I was wondering! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF is an API that can be used to create APIS within your application.

Web Services usually involves creating an API within your application. There are valid APIs that are not Web Services, like the Win32 API.

Its possible to build a WCF web service with one web method for an application that would not be considered an API specifically since it does not contain a set of routines, protocols, or tools for building applications.

Review http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface for what an API is.

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia, [yes, yes it is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface):

> APIs often come in the form of a library that includes specifications
>   for routines, data structures, object classes, and variables. In other
>   cases, notably SOAP and REST services, an API is simply a
>   specification of remote calls exposed to the API consumers.

Answer (score 0):

An API (Application Program Interface) is a way to interact with components of a system.  It defines the operations that can be used to get data out or push it in.

WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) itself is a framework for building web services and other applications that need a communication channel to share data with other services/applications, it is actually a lot larger on what it can do.  You can read more about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119(v=vs.90).aspx).  It is an API as it gives you objects that allow you to tell it interact with its' components.

REST and SOAP are just architecture styles that can be used to serve data via a service, it is defining how you should interact with the data rather than the components themselves.